# cannot open project file in blend in visual studios 2012

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

Hello I've been switching between blend and visual studio for designing and coding and I heard that you can right click an XML file and click open in blend I've looked on the context menu and it isn't there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide what is the error?

Comment: it's not an error i just don't see the button in the context menu when i right click it in solution explorere

Comment: Are you sure that Blend is installed in your machine, and what visual studio version are you using?

Comment: I'm using visual studios 2012 ultimate and I'm sure it is installed because i'm using it at the same time as visual studio right now, do I need to link it to my visual studios some how?

Comment: How about this, try opening the context menu -> Open With -> Choose blend as default?

Comment: tried that, blend says _"invalid solution file"_

Comment: Oh, I remember now. The solution must be originally be created from Expression Blend and not Visual Studio, might be a bug. Try creating a new solution from blend then open it in Visual Studio. It should be available from there.

Comment: I tried it sadly it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The Blend in Visual Studio 2012 is for Windows Phone and Windows Store apps only,

http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/

> Blend will continue to ship as a standalone tool with Visual Studio
>   2012, as part of a consolidated designer/developer offering. Blend for
>   Visual Studio 2012 provides a rich design-centric environment for
>   building Windows Store apps and Windows Phone apps. In addition,
>   Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 and later adds support for Silverlight and
>   WPF editing, as well as SketchFlow.

You will have to install Update 2 as suggested by Microsoft.